# Getting more info from System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException

Tags: c#, exception, system.data.sqlite

When `System.Data.SQLite` encounters an SQL syntax error, the only relevant info the `Message` property of `SQLiteExcption` gives is the name of the SQL error and the keyword/symbol near it. Is there a way to get more info about the error - namely, the exact location(or range) in the `CommandText` string where the error occurred?

It doesn't have to be from the `SQLiteException` - getting that info from the `SQLiteCommand` or the `SQLiteConnection` will also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is caused by a syntax error in your SQL statement. C# itself can't give you more information. It just passes your query to SQLite. SQLite then parses your query and generates a syntax error. That error is catched by C# and packaged in a `SQLiteException`. Thus, you are not asking that C# gives you more information but that SQLite does.

Unfortunately, as far as I know (and after some googling) it seems SQLite can't give you more information. The only other option I found was a program called [SQLite Developer](http://www.sqlitedeveloper.com/sqlite-developer-sqlite3-database-manager). I haven't tried it but it says it has (besides a whole other bunch of features) a syntax checker. The screenshot of that checker on that page indicates it underlines your syntax errors in your SQL statements. There is a paying version and freeware lite version. You'll have to see for yourself which one is sufficient.

Comment: I was not expecting to get the info from C# - I was just thinking maybe System.Data.SQLite is storing that info somewhere. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Well, I work primarily in TSQL so maybe someone better than me in SQLite can help you but I wouldn't count on it. It's the same problem in TSQL which makes debugging giant SQL statements sometimes a lot of 'fun'.